# Converting a Harmonic Oscillator from Trig to Exponential

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series, differential

I am currently reading *Differential equations in 24 hours with solutions and historical notes.* by Scott Imhoff, PhD. In the fifth hour we are given:
$$\ddot{y} + y = 0$$
$$y = c_1 \cos t + c_2 \sin t$$
$$ \vec{C} = <c_1, c_2>  $$
When
$ y(0) = 1 $ and $\dot{y}(0) = 0 $ then
$ \vec{C} = <1, 0> $ and $ y = \cos t $

When
$ y(0) = 0 $ and $\dot{y}(0) = 1 $ then
$ \vec{C} = <0, 1> $ and $ y = \sin t $

I observe, in general, we have $ \vec{C} = r <\cos\theta, \sin\theta > $ where (r) is the magnitude and $\theta$ is the phase angle and we can write $ y = r \cos\theta \cos t + r \sin\theta \sin t $ as a general solution.

If we let $\vec{C}$ be the complex vector $<1, i> $ then a particular solution is $ y = \cos t + i \sin t $ and we note that this is equal to exponential form $ e^{ti}$. To verify this we can do:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} e^{ti} = ie^{ti}$$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} e^{ti} = -e^{ti}$$
and see $ -e^{ti} + e^{ti} = 0$ is a particular solution to the given differential equation.

**My question is:** How do I generalize the exponential solution? That is, how do I introduce the $\vec{C}$ into the exponential form while maintaining the nice interpretation of phase angle and magnitude?

Comment: Note that $\cos t = Re \{e^{it}\} = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}2$ and $\sin t= \frac{e^{it} - e^{-it}}{2i}$. Plugging that in the general solution gives you the form $y= C_1 e^{it} + C_2 e^{-it}$, where $C_1 = \frac{c_1}2 - i\frac{c_2}2$ and $C_2 = \frac{c_1}2 + i \frac{c_2}2$. But I am not sure if this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is what you are looking for, but here we go.

You can multiply both sides by $y'$:
\begin{align*}
y'' + y = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow y''y' + y'y = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y')^{2} + y^{2} = k^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' = \pm\sqrt{k^{2} - y^{2}}
\end{align*}

Now you can apply the integration by substitution in order to get $y$.

Hopefully this helps!

**EDIT**

In order to answer your question, we can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
y(t) & = c_{1}\cos(t) + c_{2}\sin(t)\\\\
& = \sqrt{c^{2}_{1} + c^{2}_{2}}\left(\frac{c_{1}\cos(t)}{\sqrt{c^{2}_{1} + c^{2}_{2}}} + \frac{c_{2}\sin(t)}{\sqrt{c^{2}_{1} + c^{2}_{2}}}\right)\\\\
& = k\sin(t + \varphi)
\end{align*}
where $k = \sqrt{c^{2}_{1}+c^{2}_{2}}$ and

$$\varphi = \arcsin\left(\frac{c_{1}}{\sqrt{c^{2}_{1} + c^{2}_{2}}}\right)$$

If you still have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I have the solution(s). What I'm trying to understand is how to express $c_1 e^{(t+\phi)i}$ correctly so $c_1$ is the amplitude of the function and $\phi$ is the phase angle. I vaguely remember something like this from glancing at a Fourier transform video long ago, but am trying to re-derive the result for myself?

Comment: @RonJensen I have edited my answer. Hopefully it helps this time.

Comment: I am looking for an understanding of the complex exponential form of the solution as applicable to Fourier analysis.  When I wrote $ c_1e^{(t+\phi)i}$ a few minutes ago I realized $ c_1e^{(t+\phi)i} = c_1e^{(\phi)i} e^{(t)i}$ which leads back to the interpretation of $ r(\cos{\phi} + i\sin{\phi}) e^{(t)i}$ which is what I was trying to understand.